# archivo no se escribe completamente

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

Estoy mandando con un DataOutputStream el nombre de un archivo y el archivo mismo, pero no se copia completo en el destino el archivo, solo una parte de la fotografia aparece.
Perdonen mi ignorancia en lo que voy a escribir:¿podria ser una causa de que el programa no funcione bien, el hecho de que estoy mandando en un arreglo de bytes datos tipo texto con datos de tipo pixel?
Otro dato es que el nombre lo envia bien, y la foto aparece a la mitad o a veces una pequeña franja arriba.
A continuacion les dejo el codigo:

Clase Main:

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Servidor server = new Servidor();
    Thread thread = new Thread(server);
    thread.start();     
    new Ventana();

}
```

}

Clase servidor:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Servidor implements Runnable{
    private ServerSocket server;
    Socket socket;
    public boolean hilo = true;
    
    public void run() {
        //while(hilo){
            try {
                server = new ServerSocket(7483);
                socket = server.accept();
                DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                byte[] datos = new byte[1000000]; 
                input.read(datos);
                byte[][] datosArr= separar(datos);
                String nombre = aString(datosArr[0]);
                FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("c:\\Users\\julio\\Desktop\\"+nombre);
                file.write(datosArr[1]);
                input.close();
                server.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        //}
    }
    
    public byte[][] separar(byte[] arr) {
        byte[][] r  = new byte[2][];
        int n1 = -1;
        while(arr[++n1]!= '\n') {
        }
        r[0] = new byte[n1];
        r[1] = new byte[arr.length - n1 - 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            if(i < n1)
                r[0][i] = arr[i];
            else if(i > n1)
                r[1][i - n1 - 1] = arr[i];
        }
        return r;
    }
    
    public String aString(byte[] arr) {
        String r = "";
        for(byte b: arr) {
            r +=(char)b;
        }
        
        return r;
    }
}
```

Clase Ventana:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.file.Files;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Ventana extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JFileChooser fileChooser;
    private JButton buscarFoto;
    private JButton enviar;
    private JTextField nombreFoto;
    private File file;
    private PanelFoto panelFoto;
    
    public Ventana() {
        setSize(500,500);{
            
        }
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        buscarFoto = new JButton("Buscar");
        add(buscarFoto, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        buscarFoto.addActionListener(this);
        enviar = new JButton("Enviar");
        add(enviar, BorderLayout.EAST);
        enviar.addActionListener(this);
        panelFoto = new PanelFoto();
        add(panelFoto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == buscarFoto) {
            int eleccion = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            if(eleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                panelFoto.setImagen(file);
            }
        }else if(e.getSource() == enviar) {
            try {
                String nombre = file.getName() + "\n";
                byte[] nomByte = nombre.getBytes();
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.9.180",7483);
                byte[] fotoByte = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
                byte[] fotoYNombreEnvio = combinar(nomByte,fotoByte);
                DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                output.write(fotoYNombreEnvio);
                output.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public byte[] combinar(byte[] arr1, byte[] arr2) {
        int n = arr1.length + arr2.length;
        byte[] arr = new byte[n];
        int n2 = arr1.length;
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if(i < n2)
                arr[i] = arr1[i];
            else
                arr[i] = arr2[i - n2];
        }
        return arr;
    }
}
```

Comment: hay mucho codigo, y no lo lei, pero hay un socket, y el socket manda paquetes.. muchos paquetes... estas leyendo todos los paquetes??? en general uno lee el socket hasat que no haya mas nada que leer.. no se lee todo de una...

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga No se lo que son los paquetes, pero junte una foto y un string en un arreglo de bytes y lo envie, pero el servidor parece que no lee todos los byte, ya que la foto sale a medias ( el archivo)

Comment: Lee como funciona un socket.. se reciben paquetes de bytes, no todo junto. depende la implementacion, es el tamaño del paquete y vos tenes que seguir leyendo hasta que no haya nada mas que leer... si no sabes lo que son paquetes, y estas usando un socket, para ahora, y lee sobre eso...

Comment: @gbianchi-enhuelga tienes razón. Conoces algún libro bueno de java en español?

Comment: Yo no se java.. se de sockets... ;) y la implementacion suele ser parecida en cualquier lenguaje...  apuesto a que esta linea: input.read(datos); devuelve true o false... miraste la documentacion?